230 V AC signal to control 12 V DC load
Can any one suggest a simple device that on sensing a 230 V AC current will close/connect two terminals to allow an independent 12 V DC circuit to be turned on. I considered a SSR but can't find one that uses AC to control DC. I thought an SSR acted like a relay with switching side being independent of switched side (photo couple) so don't understand why AC DC types don't exist.

Get a 5V DC power supply that takes 230V (eg phone charger) and use it to power a relay with a 5V coil. Or even a solid state relay.

This works really well and is safe (+1), however note that some such devices can take more than 1 second to turn on, and don't turn off instantly either (depending on the output filter capacitors) so it might not be ideal if you need fast response or want sharp switching (for example, to maximize the life of a mechanical relay).


... a simple device that on sensing a 230 V AC current ...

I think you mean "AC voltage". Detecting AC current implies that the output would be off at zero current even if 230 V was present.

... will close/connect two terminals to allow an independent 12 V DC circuit to be turned on.

A 230 V AC relay with a normally open (NO) contact will do that.

I considered a SSR but can't find one that uses AC to control DC. I thought an SSR acted like a relay with switching side being independent of switched side (photo couple) so don't understand why AC DC types don't exist.

There just isn't the commercial demand for them. Most control systems nowadays are DC so the SSR inputs are DC. Traditionally the outputs were AC (TRIAC-based) but with the advent of better, high-voltage MOSFETs the DC output type became economic and reliable.

If OP wants an SSR on the output, cheat with a "small signal" relay with 230 V coil and 12 V DC switched into the SSR. A bit crude but would do the job. Strange form factor, but electrically ok for this: https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/phoenix-contact/2900311/2734675

look at Hi-link power supply, it can convert 230 VAC to 5V DC. you can use that to drive your relay. These power modules are really small. They can often supply 500mA or more, so it can directly drive a low current relay.
